# How can I change colors of google Icons when I'm using Materialize css?

Tags: css, material-design, materialize

I created a form for login like followed picture:
[image]

When I don't fill in anything, the icon will have black color like the email line otherwise it'll turn green like the password line. I believe its kind of default settings and apparently this is not a good color combination. I'd like to change it but as a noob here I have no idea which attribute I should change...

all css I used come from http://materializecss.com/

Here is my code of this form:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
    <form class="col s8 offset-s2" role="form" method="POST" action="{{ url('/login') }}">
      {!! csrf_field() !!}
      <div class="row">
        <div class="input-field col s12">
          <i class="material-icons prefix">account_circle</i>
          <input value="Hi" type="email" class="validate" name="email" value="{{ old('email') }}">
          <label for="email">Email</label>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="row">
        <div class="input-field col s12">
          <i class="material-icons prefix">dialpad</i>
          <label class="active" for="password">Password</label>
          <input value=" " type="password" class="validate" name="password">
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
          <div class="checkbox col s3">
            <p>
              <input type="checkbox" name="remember" id="checkbox_remember"/>
              <label for="checkbox_remember">Remember Me</label>
            </p>
          </div>
          <div class="col s4">
              <button type="submit" class="waves-effect waves-light btn">
                  <i class="material-icons left">cloud</i>Login</a>
              </button>
          </div>    
        <div class="col s5">
              <a class="waves-effect waves-light btn right" href="{{ url('/password/reset') }}">Forgot Your Password?</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just modify the css:

```
.material-icons {
  color: your color of choice;
  }
```

for the default value, and:

```
.material-icons.active {
      color: your color of choice;
    }
```

when the input is selected (focused).

Comment: Hi Ty for your reply. Ur solution is basically correct but as I explored we need to add a bit more things here to make it work. .material-icons should be changed to .mateiral-icons-prefix.

Answer (score 1):

Need to use correct pseudo-element format (colon) and add focus and hover for good measure.
    .material-icons:active, .material-icons:focus, .material-icons:hover {
              color: your color of choice;
            }